# Minitab & VBA: Call Minitab function with argument

Tags: excel, vba, automation, minitab

I want to perform a capability analysis (sixpack) with Minitab on data in an Excelfile. I want to use the lower and upper specification limit as arguments which are stored in a column of the Excelfile.

How can I call a Minitab function out of VBA and pass the argument out of Excel to this function? (Calling Minitab functions out of VBA works already)

The code:

mtbProject.ExecuteCommand "Sixpack 'Wert' 1; Lspec ; Uspec ; Pooled; AMR; CCRbar; CCAMR; UnBiased; OBiased; Breakout 25; Toler 6; CStat; Test 1 2 3."

It´s working so far, I can save the lower and upper specification limits in VBA variables but if I put them in the mtb Project.Execute...-function they don´t work anymore.

I also can access them if they are placed in an separate column but I need to have both specifications in Cell 1 + 2 of a single column.

Any suggestions which syntax to use / how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!